# How can I use a Python defaultdict to divide one value by another?

Tags: python

I have a defaultdict built with keys and values, but I need to be able to divide the first value by the second value if there are two values in the pair.

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {3: [7567, 6525], 4: [0], 65542: [609, 5245], 13:     
[73585, 84764], 14: [159, 19385], 65552: [1834], 22: [47333], 25: [0, 5320],
65562: [0], 98332: [0], 30: [0, 704249], 32: [5612], 33: [76050]}
```

So, for 3:, I would need to get 7567/6525, and put that into a new dictionary with the same key. But, for 32, I can't do any division, so I'd need to remove it from the set.

How would I go about doing this, knowing I don't always have 2 values to divide with?

Comment: Can you describe the behavior a little better? You want a dict that only lets the user set 2-tuples, and stores `(m, n)` as `m / n`, and refuses to store something that isn't a 2-tuple?

Comment: Like this? `{k: reduce(operator.div, map(float, v)) for k, v in original.items()}` (assuming you `import operator` and have your dict mapped to `original`)

Comment: @two-BitAlchemist, there's no way to force only setting 2-tuples, the data kind of is what it is right now with all the other code going on around it. What I need to do is spit back a dict with {3:[1.15], 65542:[0.11]}, and skip past 4:, 98332:, 32:, 33:, et cetera. Hell, ideally, I'd create a separate list of those outliers, if at all possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use a dictionary comprehension and the ternary operator.

Python 3

```
from operator import truediv

{key: (truediv(*val) if len(val) == 2 else val[0]) for key, val in dic.items()}
```

Python 2

```
from operator import truediv

{key: (truediv(*val) if len(val) == 2 else val[0]) for key, val in dic.iteritems()}
```

I'll continue with Python 3. If you want to remove those entries with less than 2 items

```
{key: div(*val) for key, val in dic.items() if len(val) == 2}
```

**Update** per your comment under the question

Wrapping the results back into lists and getting a list of the "outliers".

```
new_dic = {key: [div(*val)] for key, val in dic.items() if len(val) == 2}
outliers = [key for key, val in dic.items() if len(val) != 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess since everyone else is interpreting the question this way I'll post my version as an answer:

```
{k: reduce(operator.div, map(float, v)) for k, v in original.items()}
```

Alternatively:

```
{k: reduce(operator.truediv, v) for k, v in original.items()}
```

Where `original` is your dict and you `import operator`. If you're on Python 3 you'll need to `from functools import reduce` as well (global in Python 2).

<s>Also, if you're using Python 3, you can drop `map(float, v)` in favor of just `v`. That's so you don't get burned by integer division (Floor division) on Python 2.</s> You can use `truediv` instead of `map` to avoid this -- I was thinking, incorrectly, this was not portable between versions of Python. I stand corrected.

Note: This will not work if your dict values are not always iterable. You're using a defaultdict with a list default so you'll be fine.

Comment: I love `reduce`. Though I'd rather import `truediv` and avoid that map call.

Comment: Ah, for some reason I was thinking that had a different name in Python 3. That would work as well. I was attempting to make a reasonably portable version.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
for k in mydict.keys():
  if len(mydict[k]) != 2:
    mydict.pop(k)
  else:
    v1, v2 = mydict[k]
    mydict[k] = v1 / v2
```